# Package Persitence on Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, chromium

How to keep the persistence or let auto re-add libraries on EBS after reboots or automatic updates?

I have a Node.js environment deployed on an Elastic Beanstalk environment, that uses *Chromium* as a dependency.

I manually installed the library via (once connected to the instance via ***eb ssh***)

```
curl https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh
```

After automatic updates (I suppose) and reboots, the environment loses the dependencies and I need to manually reinstall it.
How do I keep the library?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I keep the library?

You have to create [.ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) to your source code. Specifically, you can install your Chrome automatically by adding it to the using [Commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands).

Alternative is to create [custom EB AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html) with per-installed dependencies.